# A book where a teen places a clock in a 'time portal' in his relatives' shed.

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Many years ago as a teen I read a book that I've been thinking a lot about recently. It was a sci fi book about a teenage boy visiting relatives (uncle or grandparents maybe). In the shed he found some sort of portal that distorted time and he placed a clock on the other end to watch it through the portal.

What is this book?

Comment: Without knowing how old you are we doing know how long ago 'Many years ago as a teen' is.  Can you add more detail,  by [edit]ing your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201742/a-book-with-two-twins-and-a-difficult-relation-a-room-where-time-flows-slower-t (which is newer)

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that the book you're looking for is [*Singularity*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(William_Sleator_novel)) by William Sleator:

> Sixteen-year-old identical twins Harry and Barry learn that their mysterious great-uncle has died, and his house and possessions now belong to their mother. The brothers travel to Sushan, Illinois to examine the house and its contents. Inside the cobweb-filled home, the rivaling brothers find mysterious animal skeletons and other odd objects. **Outside Uncle Ambrose's residence, Harry and Barry find a small metal-reinforced building**, which according to the accompanying keys, is called the "playhouse." When the twins explore the playhouse, they discover that **the properties of time are altered inside**, and the playhouse may explain the eccentricities of their great-uncle. When their quirky and cute neighbor Lucy enters their lives, competition between the twins escalates, and Harry makes a decision that will change the nature of their relationship forever.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: And there is a scene where a clock is placed just outside the cabin so a person inside can keep track of outside time